# id + 1 on append, responsive filemanager multiple select image

Tags: javascript

still looking for code, how can i have different id on input attribute each time i click add button, I have no idea on how to make the id unique ,please help me..

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn2").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(".inputclass").attr("id");
        var newid = parseInt(id) + 1;
        $('.inputclass').attr("id", ""+newid+"");

        $("#gallery").append(
             '<div class="added">'
            +'<div class="col-md-2">'
            +'<div>'
            +'<a class="fileman" href="#"" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#FileManager">'
            +'<img id="1" class="imageview center-block" src="/assets/img/noimage150x150.png"></a>'
            +'</div>'
            +'<a class="tutup btn btn-sm btn-warning">delete<a>'
            +'<input class="inputclass" name="image" type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="1"/>'
            +'</div>'
            +'</div>'
        );



    });

    $("#gallery").on('click', '.tutup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why you not pu your generated id inside of html generation code. Like this '<img id=+newId+'...class="form-control" id=+newId+'next html'...also im pretty sure that .inputclass is not unique so you should remove $('.inputclass').attr("id", ""+newid+"");.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. You just need to insert id when you generate html

```
+'<input class="otherClass" name="image" type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="'+newid+'"/>'
```

Also you need to change class name of input.

https://jsbin.com/pinegowotu/1/edit?html,console,output

Fix bin

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's works now.. thanks dude.. you save me.. sorry for late respone.. just finish from moving to new office.. god thanks dude for help me out